# wget recursive not working as expected

Tags: bash, ftp, wget

Wondering if I am overlooking the obvious

I am trying to use

```
wget -rl 0 -A "*.fna.gz" ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/bacteria/Acinetobacter_nosocomialis/all_assembly_versions
```

To download all the files in all the directories contained in `ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/bacteria/Acinetobacter_nosocomialis/all_assembly_versions/` that match `*.fna.gz`

If you visit the above link, you will see a list of directories starting with `GCA`.  I want all the files in those directories that match `*.fna.gz` but I get nothing when I run the command.  I'm wondering if wget is not recognizing the `GCA*` directories as directories, and this is the problem?  Or is there something wrong with my wget command?

I am suspicious because when I try to download the directories with FileZilla I get:

```
GCA_000248315.2_ASM24831v2: Not a regular file
Error:  Critical file transfer error
```

Comment: also tried `wget -nd -rl 0 --accept-regex ".*GCA.*/.*fna.gz" ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/bacteria/Acinetobacter_nosocomialis/all_assembly_versions/
`
hoping that it would match all files ending in .fna.gz that are located in directories and sub directories contained by directories that start with GCA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this isn't working as expected because of a bug on the server which displays symbolic links to directories as ordinary files.  Thus as @Steffen Ullrich mentioned, "There is no information in the file listing which gives the type of the target file, i.e. if directory or plain file or whatever. Thus wget will probably assume plain file and not follow it." Thanks to codesquid_ on the FileZilla IRC for the clarification.

Follow up question regarding a work around at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307325/recursive-wget-cant-get-files-within-symbolic-link-directories

Answer (score 0):

These are not directories but links to somewhere else. There is no information in the file listing which gives the type of the target file, i.e. if directory or plain file or whatever. Thus wget will probably assume plain file and not follow it.

Comment: From `ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/bacteria/Acinetobacter_nosocomialis/all_assembly_versions/` clicking on `GCA_000301695.1_ASM30169v1` leads to `ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/bacteria/Acinetobacter_nosocomialis/all_assembly_versions/GCA_000301695.1_ASM30169v1`  If I `wget -nd -rl 0 -A "*.fna.gz" ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/bacteria/Acinetobacter_nosocomialis/all_assembly_versions/GCA_000301695.1_ASM30169v1/` it works as if the "link" GCA_000301695.1_ASM30169v1 is a directory ONLY if it has the trailing `/`